# Circular data model for wind direction

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, regression, predictive-modeling

Say I have a matrix of 10 X 10 of vectors in 3D, where the dimensions include height of the specific point, speed in m/s, and angle in degrees. The test cases I have are matrices of 10 X 10, where the only given data I have are height, speed and angles of the corners [(0, 0), (0, 9), (9, 0), (9, 9)] and the heights of all other point - the speed and angles are excluded from all the points which are not the corners. I have been trying to split each angle to sin and cos, built DL architectures to try to predict such cases, but I haven't reached any satisfying results at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of DL architecture is it? Reinforcement Learning?